# align column with text and numbers

Tags: microsoft-excel, alignment

In Excel, I need to align on the decimal point a column of numbers that contains a mix of:

- numbers, and
- numbers followed by x's

For example, the following data should be aligned as:

```
  0.100
  0.220 xx
 -2.123 xxxxx
 20.123 x
-30.100
```

Is there a custom format that allows to format like this?

Many thanks!

Comment: My understanding is that a cell value must be numeric to be considered a number. As such, it is not possible to use custom formatting for this. However, you could use a formula in a different column. It would extract the number portion, format it, and then add the text bit at the end. It's important to note that Excel would see them all as text even if there weren't any X's in it. You would use the `TEXT` function in combination with `FIND` to find the space and `MID` to extract the pieces.